# How can I comment on prettierrc file

Tags: comments, prettier

I know json file cannot add comments unless I have “_comment”:”comment content”.

However, with .prettierrc file having this is going to interfere with prettier configuration.

Is there any good way of commenting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettier's configurations file doesn't have to be JSON. It can be written in JavaScript too (`.prettierrc.js` or `prettier.config.js`), with as many comments as you want.

See https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have most of my other configuration files like `.eslintrc.json` in the `json` format. So, for uniformity, I like to keep most (if not all) of my configration files in the `json` format. If, like me, you'd like to keep your prettier configuration in the `json` format (`.prettierrc.json`), here's what you can do.

Add a key called `comments` or anything of your choice to the root level of your `.prettierrc.json` and give it any value you'd like to.

Example `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "comments": {
    "trailingComma": "The default setting of all adds commas after each and every multiline function argument, even if there is only one argument. Setting this to es5 prevents this.",
    "endOfLine": "Setting this to auto prevents prettier from changing line endings (e.g., CRLF to LF or vice versa) depending on OS. The default is lf."
  }
}
```

The catch here is that when you run prettier's formatting command from the command line, i.e., `npx prettier . --write`, prettier does not recognize the key you've added (`comments` in my case) and logs a warning to the console like so:

[image]

Regardless, the formatting will go through successfully, and you'll still see prettier errors if any. If you're ok with seeing this warning each time you format, you need not read below.

If you'd like to not see that warning, you can call prettier's formatting command with a higher log level like so:

```
npx prettier . --write --log-level error
```

*prettier's default log level is `--log-level log`*

So as to not type out this command all the time, you can add a script to your `package.json` like so:

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "format": "npx prettier . --write --log-level error"
}
```

and call this script with:

```
npm run format
```

*Note that by doing the above, you're only suppressing prettier warnings on the console. This has the drawback of not being able to see other prettier warnings that might occur, but in my case, I'm fine with that, since I only occasionally format my project using prettier's cli. Most of my prettier formatting happens using my project's `vscode` settings (in combination with the prettier vscode extension), i.e.:*

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```